# React.js How to render component inside component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am stuck. I have several seperate components on seperate files.  If I render them in main.jsx like following:

```
ReactDOM.render(<LandingPageBox/>, document.getElementById("page-landing")); 
ReactDOM.render(<TopPlayerBox topPlayersData={topPlayersData}/>, document.getElementById("wrapper profile-data-wrapper"));
ReactDOM.render(<RecentGamesBox recentGamesData={recentGamesData}/>, document.getElementById("history wrapper"));
```

Everything works fine, but I wonder if it is a good practice? Maybe it is possible to do something like there would be only one ReactDom.render like:

```
ReactDOM.render(<LandingPageBox recentGamesData={recentGamesData} topPlayersData={topPlayersData}/>, document.getElementById("page-landing"));
```

I tried different kinds of variatons of LandingPageBox to somehow include those other two components, but had no luck. They sometimes rendered outside the page and so on. I thought it should look something like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import RecentGames from '../RecentGames/RecentGames.jsx';
import TopPlayers from '../TopPlayers/TopPlayers.jsx';
import PageTop from './PageTop.jsx';
import PageBottom from './PageBottom.jsx';

class LandingPageBox extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <body className="page-landing">
                <PageTop>
                     <TopPlayers topPlayersData={this.props.topPlayersData} />
                </PageTop>
                <PageBottom>
                        <RecentGames recentGamesData=    {this.props.recentGamesData}/>
                    </PageBottom>              
                </body>
            );
        }
    }

export default LandingPageBox;
```

But this code only renders PageTop and PageBottom, without player or game components.

So my question would be, how to set up LandingPageBox file so that TopPlayers component would render inside PageTop component and RecentGames component would render inside PageBottom component? Thank you.

Comment: Why do you not using `this.props.children`?

Comment: I tried reading about it, but I just can't understand the concept. How does React knows which child to use if I have as in this example two? Also Maybe I wasn't clear on one thing too, that is that page should be rendered first, then inside of it those two components should be rendered, because page components have containers in which those components have to be put.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

In your example

```
return (
        <body className="page-landing">
            <PageTop>
                 <TopPlayers topPlayersData={this.props.topPlayersData} />
            </PageTop>
            <PageBottom>
                 <RecentGames recentGamesData=    {this.props.recentGamesData}/>
            </PageBottom>              
        </body>
       );
```

React will only render the top-level custom components `PageTop` and `PageBottom`, as you already found out. The other components (`TopPlayers` and `RecentGames`) are **nested** within those components. What does that mean? React does not just display those nested components because it would not know how to do this. Instead, all rendering must be done by the outer components `PageTop` and `PageBottom`. React just passes the nested components to them (`PageTop` gets `TopPlayers`, `PageBottom` gets `RecentGames`) in `this.props.children`. Now it is **up to the outer components** what to do with these nested components. In your example, you would modify the `PageTop` and `PageBottom` components to use `{this.props.children}` to display their nested components in a suitable way.

Comment: Thank you. Very good explanation. Everything works like a charm.

Answer (score 45):

You are right. You can use as many nested components as you want. It's one of the main concepts in react.
You can access them in `this.props.children`. 
Do it like this:

```
var Parent = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <div>{this.props.children}</div>;
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Parent>
    <Child/>
    <Child/>
  </Parent>,
  node
);
```

Read more here - https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html

And here - http://buildwithreact.com/article/component-children

Comment: Maybe you could show me where to put {this.props.children} in my example? I am very new to React.js.

Comment: Great references!

Comment: After spending hours and I finally found this! Thanks mate!

Answer (score 2):

Here Car component is inside the another component i.e Garage components.
When Garage component in rendering Car component is also renders.
Same concept as like one function inside another function.

```
class Car extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <h2>I am a Car!</h2>;
  }
}

class Garage extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <h1>Who lives in my Garage?</h1>
      <Car />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Garage />, document.getElementById('root'));
```