# Is it possible to open another functional component upon firing an event within a functional component in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I wonder if it is possible to render (or open) a `Functional (Stateless)` component within another Functional component upon for example `onClick` event? Let's assume the following primitive component;

```
const FunctionalComponent = () => {
    <div>
        <h1>Don't snub me because I'm primitive </h1>
        <a href="#" onClick={handleClick}>
            Click to open another functional component
        </a>
    </div>
};
```

Is there a way to open another functional component upon clicking the `link` (or `button`, etc.)?

Notice that I am trying to understand if this is doable without using the `State Object` of the `React Class` or `React Router`.

More generally, I am looking for **the best practice in rendering different** `React`**components upon triggering an** `event`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React.js How to render component inside component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35969495/react-js-how-to-render-component-inside-component)

Comment: The problem in the that question is not the same. My question is how to render a functional component upon a fired event in another functional component.

Comment: Why do you want to solve a *stateful problem* with a *stateless function component* ?!?

Comment: Why do I need to hold a state just for linking another page on button? I mean, why do we need a stateful component for just implementing the old-school href feature?

Comment: @GokhanKaradag I'd recommend spending some time learning about the "React way" of thinking. Here's a link to get you started: https://daveceddia.com/thinking-statefully/

Comment: @camden thank you for that nice article, I've got it and agreed. On the other hand, what is your way of of implementing simple href feature?

Comment: cant you just use react-router-dom?

Comment: @Omar, sure. I know we can use 'Link'. then I have to declare the proper routing first within the 'Router' object. But, I am relatively new to React and would like to figure out more efficient ways if available.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible to do entirely within this component, because it's *stateless*. However, you could pass two props, `isOtherComponentShown` and `onClick` to this component from its parent (stateful) component, and control the rendering of your other component that way.