# Is there anyway to render react component inside return using template literals?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to use the react component inside return using template literals, however, it is not working. I did lots of research, in the maximum site only given for rendering HTML tags inside template literals.

Please suggest.

```
import IconButton from '@abc/components'  

export const ColumnsOfBryntum = (recordType) => {
render() => {
   switch (recordType) {
      case 'kpi':
      return `<div>
            <div class="channel-info">
            <div class="channel-name">${value}</div>                
            ${<IconButton icon="plus"></IconButton>}
      </div>`;
    case 'channelGroup':
      size.height = 50;
      row.addCls('channel-group-row');
      return `<div>
           <div class="channel-info">
           <div class="channel-name">${value}</div>              
           ${<IconButton icon="edit"></IconButton>}
      </div>`;
   }
}
```

}

Output: [Object Object]

Comment: Why not return JSX instead of a string?

Comment: Please take reference from the below link, it should solve your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35969495/react-js-how-to-render-component-inside-component

Comment: As Nick says, you could just return JSX, a div is valid syntax for jsx, you could wrap all of the return on a React Fragment

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work
    import IconButton from '@abc/components'

```
export const ColumnsOfBryntum = (recordType) => {
render() => {
   switch (recordType) {
      case 'kpi':
      return <IconButton icon="plus"></IconButton>;
    case 'channelGroup':
      size.height = 50;
      row.addCls('channel-group-row');
      return <IconButton icon="edit"></IconButton>;
   }
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that we have another div as well, so couldn't use as  return <IconButton icon="plus"></IconButton>;

Comment: Well then try this

Comment: export const ColumnsOfBryntum = (recordType) => {
render() => {
   switch (recordType) {
      case 'kpi':
      return <div><IconButton icon="plus" /></div>;
    case 'channelGroup':
      size.height = 50;
      row.addCls('channel-group-row');
      return <div><IconButton icon="edit" /></div>;
   }
}

Answer (score 0):

```
export const ColumnsOfBryntum = ({ recordType }) => {
  switch (recordType) {
    case 'kpi':
      return (
        <div className="channel-info">
          <div className="channel-name">{value}</div>
          <IconButton icon="plus"></IconButton>
        </div>
      );
    case 'channelGroup':
      size.height = 50;
      row.addCls('channel-group-row');
      return (
        <div className="channel-info">
          <div className="channel-name">{value}</div>
          <IconButton icon="edit"></IconButton>
        </div>
      );
    default:
      return null;
  }
};
```

Assuming you pass `recordType` as a prop, you need to add curly brackets to destructure it. Given the code you provided, `value`, `size` and `row` will still be undefined. You were also missing some closing tags. I went ahead and removed the outer `divs`, since they have no class or inline styling.